# Issue With Yaml Variable Assignment With Bash

Tags: bash, azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I am having issues when trying to assign variables with the following syntax in a yaml file. The follow code is taken from the Microsoft Doc on [Define variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch) under the section **Understand variable syntax**:

```
variables:
- name: one
  value: initialValue 

steps:
  - script: |
      echo ${{ variables.one }} # outputs initialValue
      echo $(one)
    displayName: First variable pass
  - bash: echo '##vso[task.setvariable variable=one]secondValue'
    displayName: Set new variable value
  - script: |
      echo ${{ variables.one }} # outputs initialValue
      echo $(one) # outputs secondValue
    displayName: Second variable pass
```

Specifically I found the issue being in the area with the syntax `'##vso[task.setvariable variable=one]secondValue'`
Note: That I am not using a string written straight into the line above I am using a bash variable with the syntax `$variableName` in place of `secondValue`

The issue is:

```
variables:
- name: one
  value: "initialValue" 

steps:
- task: Bash@3
    inputs:
        targetType: 'inline'
        script: |
            valueTwo="New Value"
            echo '##vso[task.setvariable variable=one]$valueTwo'
    displayName: "Change Variable"

- task: Bash@3
    inputs:
        targetType: 'inline'
        script: |
            echo $(one)
    displayName: "Check Variable Has Changed"
```

Expected Output: `New Value`
Real Output: `$valueTwo`

Comment: You're talking about _issues_ and _the issue_ without stating what issues you have.

Comment: I have updated my question to include an example of the issue at hand. Thank you for pointing that out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *parameter expansion* called for here is not executed within single quotes, so use double quotes:

```
            echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=one]$valueTwo"
```